# Sorting an SQL resultset in Delphi TDBGrid where resultset includes Firebird RDB$DB_KEY (Order By isn't working)

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I've noticed something strange and I'm not quite sure what to make of it. The result set below is basically the output of an SQL Select statement on a table where my application writes its log messages. I've edited out the sensitive material like site and task details and provided you with the field datatypes rather than the fieldnames, except for `RDB$DB_KEY` which is built into Firebird tables. *What I want you to focus on is the order of rows which I have listed despite using **Order by RDB$DB_KEY** in my SQL.*

```
Timestamp Field             Varchar Field           RDB$DB_KEY
========================    ======================  =================
19.12.2013, 10:40:40.000    Site_BC DB_2 connected  00000083:00000100
19.12.2013, 10:40:40.000    Site_BC DB_1 connected  00000083:000000fc
19.12.2013, 10:40:40.000    DB_1 tasks completed    00000083:000000fd
19.12.2013, 10:40:40.000    Site_A DB_2 connected   00000083:000000fe
```

Now, I could have sworn that `0` comes before `1` in the ASCII table, so the order of the rows (supposedly sorted in ascending order by the values in the RDB$DB_KEY field) didn't seem right to me.

I did some basic research and apparently this RDB$DB_KEY field is an array of byte (although I'm not sure). I've tried casting it as a varchar and as a char but it seems the Firebird `Cast` doesn't support conversion from this datatype.

Can anybody help me to get these rows sorted properly? I know I could add another column of integer datatype and then sort by that, but I thought I'd ask anyway just in case somebody knows how to sort by this mixed blessing called RDB$DB_KEY.

I'm using Firebird version 2.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RDB$DB_KEY` output in your select is just formatted for presentation on the client. It is not the actual key(!). The actual `RDB$DB_KEY` is (for tables) an eight byte array (or a 64 bit number).

Now as to the ordering, I am not 100% sure about the exact implementation, but either the RDB$DB_KEY is big-endian, or this presentation is big-endian). In big-endian `0x0100` comes before `0x00fc` (in little endian it would be `0x0001` and `0xfc00`).

But as I already indicated in the comments, ordering by `RDB$DB_KEY` almost never makes sense. The `RDB$DB_KEY` represents a 'snapshot' of the physical location of a record that is only really valid for the duration of a transaction (simplified). The order of the `RDB$DB_KEY` of multiple records usually does not reflect the insert order (and if it would, that order might be different after a back up and restore), but only the relative position on storage (for the currently visible record version).

Comment: Your point about backup and restore is what convinces me not to use it. Otherwise I call this big-endian stuff a bug in the implementation since it doesn't obey the rules of the Order By clause (If it can't be ordered, then there's a bug in the implementation). [+1]. Thanks.

Comment: @Sam It is not a bug: you can order by `RDB$DB_KEY`; that its (consistent!) ordering doesn't fit your expectations is something different entirely.

Comment: I can "Order By" but it doesn't sort in ascending order, therefore it doesn't work, therefore it's a bug. If the ASCII table was changed overnight and suddenly the letter "C" preceded the letter "A" that doesn't mean that C should now precede A in a sorted resultset. The internals of the encoding/decoding of individual field values doesn't change the meaning of what "sort in ascending order" implies to the user, therefore the Order By implementation is broken. It doesn't satisfy the spec, or it's misrepresented as providing sorting capability when infact it redefines what sorting is.

Comment: Then we disagree, because it does sort in ascending order. That order (or the **presentation** of the values) is just not what **you** expect. Also I could define a collation or characterset where C sorts before A, with that C sorting before A would be correct.

Comment: So if I put my car into Drive gear and then find that the car is traveling in Reverse that's not a bug because I should consider the internal workings of my transmission? If one of my wheels falls off I could just rename my car into a tricycle and pretend that everything is ok? I guess we'll just agree to disagree. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a pity noone else replied and you had to choose the "it's your problem" answer.

```
order by cast(rdb$db_key as blob)
```

I may be wrong but I suspect that FB only uses the first byte when sorting db_key by default.